# Need to solve definite integral equation, I am not sure how to proceed.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[Can anyone solve this equation? Need to solve for definite integral. I have explained how I tried to solve the equation and also mentioned the distribution of $v$. ]

$ \frac{1}{u}\log\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{u\mu_\mathrm{o}}p\left(|h_{1}|^2\right)d\left(|h_{1}|^2\right)\right)$

$\mu_\mathrm{o} = \frac{|h_1|^2}{|h_2|^2}P$

What I have done:

putting the value of $\mu_\mathrm{o}$,

$ \frac{1}{u}\log\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{u\frac{|h_1|^2P}{|h_2|^2}}p\left(|h_{1}|^2\right)d\left(|h_{1}|^2\right)\right)$

$\frac{|h_1|^2}{|h_2|^2}=v$

by substituting the value of $v$, I am not sure how to deal with $h_2$.

the distribution of the random variable i.e. $p(v) = \frac{1}{(v+1)^2}$

Comment: Use $\frac{uP}{|h_2|^2}=\alpha$ and $|h_1|^2=x$. Then your integral becomes $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\alpha x}}{(x+1)^2}dx$$ This can be expressed in terms of [generalized exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Generalization)

Comment: Thanks Adrei for the help but I don't want $h_1$ and $h_2$ in my final answer. Is there anything that has to be done with double integration?